# AndEngine how to remove bullets and shoot one bullets at a time?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm using Andengine for android and I created a code where my player will shoot a bullet when I touch the screen.

Now I want to do 2 things

first: I want the bullet to be removed when it collides with the enemy
Second: I want to be able to shoot only bullet at a time. So as long as the bullets haven't hit the enemy I don't want the method of firing a bullet to be called.

Here's the code I created
I minimized all the codes that are not really important

```
public class ShooterActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements IOnSceneTouchListener,IAccelerometerListener{

//Variables
private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private Camera mCamera;
private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
private TiledTextureRegion mTiledTextureRegion;
private TextureRegion mBulletTextureRegion;
private AnimatedSprite facebox;
private AnimatedSprite enemy;
private Sprite bulletsprite;
private Scene mScene;
private PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;
private Shape ground, roof, right, left;
private Body body, bulletbody, enemybody;
private FixtureDef mFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);
private TiledTextureRegion enemyTiled;
private boolean pFlippedHorizontal = true;



@Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0,0,CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT),this.mCamera));
}

@Override
public void onLoadResources() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024,1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    this.mTiledTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "gfx/player.png", 0, 0, 8, 1);
    this.enemyTiled = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "gfx/enemy.png", 200, 500, 8, 1);
    this.mBulletTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "gfx/badge.png", 200, 200);
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(mBitmapTextureAtlas);
}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    mScene = new Scene();
    mScene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0,0,0));
    this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0,SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);
    //Walls
    final FixtureDef wallFixture = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    roof = new Rectangle(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2);
    ground = new Rectangle(0,CAMERA_HEIGHT ,CAMERA_WIDTH,2);
    left = new Rectangle(0,0,2,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    right = new Rectangle(CAMERA_WIDTH -2, 0,2,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixture);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, roof, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixture);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, left, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixture);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, right, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixture);
    this.mScene.attachChild(roof);
    this.mScene.attachChild(ground);
    this.mScene.attachChild(left);
    this.mScene.attachChild(right);
    //facebox
    facebox = new AnimatedSprite(150,150, this.mTiledTextureRegion);
    facebox.setScale(.75f);
    facebox.animate(200);
    body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, facebox, BodyType.DynamicBody, mFixtureDef);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(facebox,body,true,false));
    this.mScene.attachChild(facebox);
    //enemy
    enemy = new AnimatedSprite(500,150,this.enemyTiled);
    enemy.animate(200);
    enemy.setScale(.75f);
    enemy.setFlippedHorizontal(pFlippedHorizontal);
    this.mScene.attachChild(enemy);
    enemybody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, enemy, BodyType.DynamicBody, mFixtureDef);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(enemy,enemybody,true,false));
    //scene
    this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
    this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(mPhysicsWorld);
    return mScene;

}

@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

//touch the screen to create bullets
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fire();
            }

        });

        //here I want to be able to remove the bullets when it hits the enemy but not sure what method to use
        this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(bulletsprite.collidesWith(enemy)){
                }   
            }
            @Override
            public void reset() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
//method to create bullets
public void fire(){
    bulletsprite = new Sprite(this.facebox.getX() + 15, this.facebox.getY() -5, this.mBulletTextureRegion);
    bulletsprite.setScale(.5f);
    bulletbody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, bulletsprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, mFixtureDef);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(bulletsprite, bulletbody, true, true));
    final Vector2 speed = Vector2Pool.obtain(50, 0);
    bulletbody.setLinearVelocity(speed);
    Vector2Pool.recycle(speed);
    this.mScene.attachChild(bulletsprite);
}

//nothing here just accelerometer
@Override
public void onAccelerometerChanged(AccelerometerData pAccelerometerData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pAccelerometerData.getX() *3, 10);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);
    Vector2Pool.recycle(gravity);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    this.enableAccelerometerSensor(this);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    this.disableAccelerometerSensor();
}
```

}

Comment: I've provided an answer that will get you somewhere, but Dan has a point - the answer to your question is "implement collision detection", which is not something that can be explained succinctly - therefore it's unlikely that you'll get a code sample as an answer, unless your question is more narrow, and focused.

Comment: Do I know to provide more information or just how I asked the question?

Answer (score 1):

First, google collision detection - that will help you solve the first problem.

Second, only keep 1 instance of the bullet object, and when it either (a) collides with the enemy or another object, or (b) goes off the screen, then you make the bullet able to be shot again.

Comment: I know about the collision detection. If you looked into my code I have it there and also a comment about it. What I don't know about is how am I going to remove the bullets when the collision happens. I know only 2 methods that removes a sprite. detachChild() and detachSelf();

Comment: You could just set a boolean on it called something like `inFlight`, that when `true` indicates that the bullet is in flight, and has not yet collided with anything. When it does collide with something, calculate the damage, and set `inFlight` to false. This then indicates that the bullet (a) should not be rendered to the screen, and (b) that it's ready to be fired again. You'll also need to reset its position, and not have it move at all while `inFlight` is false. Tapping the screen changes `inFlight` to true, only if it's already false, and triggers the firing.

Comment: thanks for this. I solved the one where I can only shoot one bullet at a time, do you know how can I remove completely the bullets? setting its visible to false and detaching it only makes it not visible. It's like the players in my game is colliding with an invisible object.

Comment: That's really up to you - but you could simply set the bullet to null, or reinitialize it every time it collides, resetting it to some kind of default state. There's a couple different ways to do it, but basically treat the collision as an event, and the `visible` attributes should be used as a signal to the rest of your program to reset the bullet. How exactly you do that, is up to the way your specific implementation. I hope that's helpful.